# Dask: Multiprocessing works on Mac but not on Windows

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, scheduler, dask

My dask multiprocessing code to apply two different lambda apply functions works perfectly on Mac but cannot run on a Windows 7 server. I can run the code with threading on Windows 7 but it's very slow. When I try scheduler processes on the  Windows 7 server, CPU usage on all cores hit 100% and the server freezes.

I can run the code below in Windows using `scheduler = 'threads'` or by specifying `num_workers` but it doesn't seem to engage all cores. With num_workers or threading on the Mac, it is much slower than `scheduler='multiprocessing'`.

Is there some additional code needed for Windows not to overload the cores/workers?

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as ddf
import multiprocessing

daskdf = ddf.from_pandas(mypandasdataframe, npartitions=4*multiprocessing.cpu_count())


def removecw(df):
    for word in mylist:
        df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\b{}$'.format(re.escape(word)), '', x))
    return df


daskdf = daskdf.map_partitions(removecw, meta = daskdf)
daskdf = daskdf.compute(scheduler='processes')

daskdf.to_csv('outputfilename')
```

On my Mac I can run the code with the expected result (removing common  words from the end of the strings in column A). When I try scheduler processes on the  Windows 7 server, CPU usage on all cores hit 100% and the server freezes.

Answer (score 0):

Windows handles multiprocessing a bit differently than Mac and Linux.

My guess is that your problem is due to trying to pass a function that is difficult to serialize.  Maybe it implicitly depends on variables that are not passed in or maybe it is defined dynamically.  Here are some things that you might try, but no guarantees:

1. Define your function in a separate module
2. Make sure that your function doesn't implicitly depend on any global variables.  If you need some additional variable, like `mylist` then pass it in explicitly (the `apply` method can take additional keyword arguments)
3. Try the distributed scheduler on your local machine.  https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/scheduling.html#dask-distributed-local

Comment: Thanks for this @MRocklin. For future coding, I'll try your 1. and 2. suggestions. It ended up working on Windows 7 if I used the threading scheduler along with specifying the number of workers manually, i.e. `df.compute(num_workers =)` and I set it equal to the number of CPUs.